# What does this section of code do

Tags: java, for-loop, int, counter

Can someone explain what exactly this code is and what it is doing? thanks!!

```
for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++) {
    counter = 0;
    for (int n = 2; n < i; n++) {
        if (i % n == 0) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter == 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bad algorithm to find prime numbers between 2 and max .

Comment: Didn't you run the code yourself and then saw that the output 2,3,5,7,11,13... could be prime numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Its printing the prime numbers between 2 and max.

It works as below:

```
start with i as 2 and step by one every time
check with every element less than i (so if i is 5, check with 2,3,4) that divide by number i and if it is increment the counter.
if counter is 0, print that number
```

Answer (score -1):

```
+program to generate prime number between 2 and MAX
but the time complexity is more, u can reduce it by
for(i=2;i<=MAX;i++)
{
  count=0;
   for(n=2;n<=i/2;n++)
   { 
     if(i%n==0)
      {
        count=1;
        break;
      }
  }
  if(count==0)
     Sop(i);    
}
```

Comment: Stating just what result is produced and handing the OP another function does not really answer the question. You should improve your answer by either explaining to the OP how their code generated those prime numbers step by step or at least why your code is more efficient, which would help the OP understand why their code works as it does.

Comment: sop(i) means System.out.println(i),2nd thing no need to iterate 2nd loop i times bcse a number is  not divisible till  half of the number,means it will not divisible by any number except itself. and 3rd one assume i is 100 which is divisible by 2 in first iterate therefore no need to check further break the inner loop.

Comment: A good explanation for why it is faster, which helps, but it still does not explain to the OP why their code works as it does. @almasshaikh answer breaks down the algorithm to its base parts and explains each loop which it is why it is a better answer to the OP's question. Also you should edit your comment into the answer.